# Saxon/X PHP API Stylesheet compilation failed - get useful error notice

Tags: php, xslt, saxon

I use in my PHP the Saxon/C API as XSLT 2.0 Processor version 1.0.0. I used Version 0.3, which compiled my Stylesheets perfectly. Unfortunately 0.3 had a bug in one function I needed, so I upgraded to 1.0.0. The bug is gone but now it does not compile my XSTL and says

```
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException : Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported
```

which is absolutely not helpful. The stylesheet includes dozens of files and is really complex (otherwise I would use libxml) so I don't have the slightiest chance to find out what's wrong (or post it here) without a proper error message.
**So, how can I get an error Message I could work with?**

Thanks in advance!

--

My PHP code (rather the example mentioned [here](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html#php-api)):

```
$saxonProc = new \Saxon\SaxonProcessor();
$saxon = $saxonProc->newXsltProcessor();
$saxon->setSourceFromFile('source.xml');
$saxon->compileFromFile('style.xml');
$result = $saxon->transformToString();

if($result == NULL) {
    $errCount = $saxon->getExceptionCount();
    if($errCount > 0 ){
        for($i = 0; $i < $errCount; $i++) {
            $errCode = $saxon->getErrorCode(intval($i));
            $errMessage = $saxon->getErrorMessage(intval($i));
            echo 'Error: Code='.$errCode.' Message='.$errMessage;
        }
        $saxon->exceptionClear();
    }
}

echo $result;

$saxon->clearParameters();
$saxon->clearProperties();
```

The  beginning of the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:t="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="t" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

   <xsl:include href="global-varsandparams.xsl"/>
```

Comment: Hi, does the apache2 error log file detail anything useful about the error? Usually the exact error will appear there. If not then you could try running the stylesheet in C/C++ using the following C program. When compiled allows you to run Saxon/C from the commandline like the Java version using the same options: https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.6/hec/Saxon.C.API/Transform.c Also see the bug issue on this with details of how to compile and run it: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2422

Comment: Also the following line seems wrong: $saxon->compileFromFile('style.xml');

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life once again. I was find the problem this way (I could have thought about the error log by myself, but I didn't, no Idea why. Interestingly it's the tunnel attribute in a param declaration. Apparently Saxon/C 1.0.0 fails on the tunnel="yes" attribute and says "Error at xsl:call-template on line 12 column 37 of style.xml:
  XTSE0680: Parameter xxx is not declared in the called template" which seems to be a bug. I will open a Issue in your tracker, okay?

Comment: Please do open a bug on the main saxon project as I think it is something in the core product: https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact error details should appear in apache log file. Also the cumulated errors should be accessible via the getErrorCode and getErrorMessage. I see you have calls to that in your example. If it is not appearing here then I suspect this is a bug worth submitting.

Comment: No getErrorMessage only says "net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException : Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported" as I told above. I will open a Bug Issue for that too.